# Reshape or recreate code for neural network output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, kaggle

i'm trying to create a neural network model for a kaggle competition using mnist dataset. currently, my code looks like this since i am trying to capture certain metrics. however, i can't seem to figure out how to turn this into an output to submit.

current:

```
import time
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()

#requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

# Load training and testing data directly from TensorFlow
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)
```

```
# Initialize metrics
metrics = {}
# Initialize metric names
names = ['Number of Hidden Layers', 'Nodes per Layer', 'Time in Seconds',
         'Training Set Accuracy', 'Test Set Accuracy']

# Set fixed parameters
n_epochs = 20
batch_size = 50
learning_rate = 0.01


# Function that creates batch generator used in training
def shuffle_batch(X, y, batch_size):
    rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
    n_batches = len(X) // batch_size
    for batch_idx in np.array_split(rnd_idx, n_batches):
        X_batch, y_batch = X[batch_idx], y[batch_idx]
        yield X_batch, y_batch
```

```
# Start timer
start = time.process_time()

n_hidden = 300

# Reset the session
tf.reset_default_graph()
#ops.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(2141)
#tf.random.set_seed(2141)
np.random.seed(9347)

# Set X and y placeholders
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None), name="y")

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, name="hidden1",
                              activation=tf.nn.relu)
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden, name="hidden2",
                              activation=tf.nn.relu)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 10, name="outputs")
    y_proba = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,
                                                              logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for X_batch, y_batch in shuffle_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size):
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test})

# Record the clock time it takes
duration = time.process_time() - start

metrics['Model 1'] = [2, n_hidden, duration, acc_train, acc_test]
```

```
# Convert metrics dictionary to dataframe for display
results_summary = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(metrics, orient='index')
results_summary.columns = names

# Sort by model number
results_summary.reset_index(inplace=True)
results_summary.sort_values(by=['index'], axis=0, inplace=True)
results_summary.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
results_summary.index.name = None

# Export to csv
results_summary.to_csv('results_summary.csv')
results_summary
```

i need to create an output that looks something like this in csv file:

```
  ImageId   Label
0   1        2
1   2        0
2   3        9
3   4        0
4   5        3
```

would i have to recreate the whole thing in order to actually create "y_pred" when doing something like `model.predict(X_test)`, or can i just reshape the existing code in some way to do this? ideally, i would like to capture predicted values and compare them to true values using a confusion matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using old tensorflow style, predict using old tensorflow style at the end:

```
feed_dict = {X: X_test}
classification = tf.run(y_proba, feed_dict)
label = numpy.argmax(classification, axis=-1)
```

Maybe you need to create a new session for this, or use the existing `sess.run`, I'm not sure how this works, try to see which option gives out reasonable results.

Comment: are you asking about how to run it? if so, i added more code to show how i'm doing it